# How to close all the ports in ubuntu except those I need them

Tags: server, .desktop, portscan

I am new in the field of security but I understand that it´s helpful to know also such things. 
May I ask you how to see all open ports in ubuntu and also how do I close all the ports except those which I need them.
Thanks nicolae

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nmap` to show you all open ports.

Open a terminal and install the `nmap` application:

```
sudo apt install nmap
```

*The nmap man pages can be brought up using `man nmap` which can show you all the commands you can use after it is installed.*

After it is installed, you can scan all the ports that are open on your host with the `-p` switch of `nmap` like the following (I set it to scan all ports from 1 to 65535):

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ nmap -p1-65535 10.0.0.100

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-29 23:28 MDT
Nmap scan report for terrance-ubuntu.local (10.0.0.100)
Host is up (0.00025s latency).
Not shown: 65522 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
22/tcp    open  ssh
25/tcp    open  smtp
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
902/tcp   open  iss-realsecure
1936/tcp  open  unknown
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt
17500/tcp open  db-lsp
32400/tcp open  unknown
32469/tcp open  unknown
33400/tcp open  unknown
33443/tcp open  unknown
```

You can kill the process that has the port open like webmin (or port 10000) on my list, or you can use `iptables` to create a simple rule to `DROP` the packets to that port for the time being until next reboot  (If you want them permanent you might want to install the `iptables-persistent` package):

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j DROP
```

Then if you want to add it back for this session, delete the rule:

```
sudo iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j DROP
```

Examples below:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j DROP

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ nmap -p1-65535 10.0.0.100
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-29 23:49 MDT
Nmap scan report for terrance-ubuntu.local (10.0.0.100)
Host is up (0.00028s latency).
Not shown: 65522 closed ports
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp    open     ftp
22/tcp    open     ssh
25/tcp    open     smtp
139/tcp   open     netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open     microsoft-ds
902/tcp   open     iss-realsecure
1936/tcp  open     unknown
10000/tcp filtered snet-sensor-mgmt
17500/tcp open     db-lsp
32400/tcp open     unknown
32469/tcp open     unknown
33400/tcp open     unknown
33443/tcp open     unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.13 seconds

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j DROP

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ nmap -p1-65535 10.0.0.100
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-29 23:49 MDT
Nmap scan report for terrance-ubuntu.local (10.0.0.100)
Host is up (0.00027s latency).
Not shown: 65522 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
22/tcp    open  ssh
25/tcp    open  smtp
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
902/tcp   open  iss-realsecure
1936/tcp  open  unknown
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt
17500/tcp open  db-lsp
32400/tcp open  unknown
32469/tcp open  unknown
33400/tcp open  unknown
33443/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.10 seconds
```

Hope this helps!